# Calculate the remaining width of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just need help making an element fit the remaining space of a div, that is covered by a fixed position element.
Over-simplifying: I have a left-fixed menu and it  has 25% of total width BUT a limit: max-width: 350px and min-width: 280px.
I also have a center aligned div that has 80% of width.
I want to put content in the second div, between the point where the divs touch, and the left margin.
I already tryed to put a spacing div between the div start and the menu end, (to the content take the rest of the space), but i reached the conclusion that it is imposible to make those calculations with css due to the min and max widths. (If i change the screen res. the width may change OR NOT).

How can i fix this?
Its javascript a good idea?

Comment: A link to your webpage or a jsfiddle showing your problem would help us to help you.

Comment: I think thay Satya answer solves the question.
I will try now, but anyway, where is what i want: http://jsfiddle.net/6BTc7/1/
If there is a way to do it without javascript, then will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think either [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BTc7/24/) or [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BTc7/25/) may get you what you want. In either case, I used a pseudo-element to generate a `float` to space it.

```
#container:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin-left: -12.5%; /* push float to left edge based on 80% container width */
    width: 31.25%; /* make float 25% of total width based off its 80% container */    
    max-width: 350px;
    min-width: 280px;
    height:100%; /* or 90% in first fiddle */
}
```

The second fiddle also has `overflow: hidden` set on the `#content` if you want it kept right always. Both also require a `height: 100%` set on the `body` and `html` tag.

Comment: @Claudiop--Yes, that and the percent calculations based on the 80% container width were key to resolving it. Glad it was what you sought.

Comment: Should i create a "fallback" stylesheet for IE7?
The :before element is not recognised in IE7, but it is in IE8 and 9.
Im not caring alot for IE7, but is always good to support a browser that a lot of r*t*rded people still use today...

Comment: @Claudiop--You can, or you can use one of many javascript solutions ([like PIE](http://css3pie.com/)) to make the older browsers behave more like the new ones.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this type javascript

```
var a =$('#id of outer div').height();
var b = $('#id of inner div').height();
var c = a-b;
$('#id of filling div').css("height",c);
```

Comment: Why doesn't this works?
var a =$('#sidemenu').width();
var b = $('#content-container').width();
var c = $('body').width();
var d = a-((c-b)/2);
$('#content').css("width",d);

Comment: here may be i guess u are calculating width wrong. if you update the code in jsfiddle and give me link i can help you

Comment: Who edited the file, forgot my only problem.
I don't need to know how to calculate the width, while the menu width is a percentage.
I want to be able to do it, even when the menu reaches max and min width, that is a constant.
Otherwise, it will not work in smaller and bigger resolutions, because the content will go under the menu, or will be miles away from the menu.